# How do I have a hyperlink in one cell specific to a dropdown option?

Tags: google-sheets

If I have a dropdown in A1.  When I select a specific value in the dropdown, I would like B1 to have a link to a Youtube video specific to that dropdown value.  So B1 would change when I select a different value in A1.

I'm guessing I need a list in another sheet with two columns.

Answer (score 0):

### Creating a second sheet with two columns is a good solution, you can do it as following:

1. Paste your data in the second sheet

   [image]
2. Create in the first column of the first sheet a dropdown menu with [data validation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/186103?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en)

   [image]

   ---

   [image]
3. Use in the second column the formula `=VLOOKUP(A1, Sheet2!A1:B,2)`.

   [Vlookup](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318?hl=en) allows you to find the value corresponding to the chosen dropdown option.

   [image]